# Integration by substitution.

Tags: integration

Integrating $$\int (x^2+2)(x-1)^7    dx$$

Let $ u = x^2 + 2$ then $ \frac{du}{dx} = 2x$

I can't see where to go after this?

I may have chosen the wrong substitution. Would it help if I let let $ u = \sqrt{u-2} $?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First note that it would be possible to expand this polynomial and integrate term by term, though this would be fairly annoying. However, if we make the substitution $u=x-1$, we can get rid of some of the work:

$\begin{align} \int(x^2+2)(x-1)^7\,dx&=\int((u+1)^2+2)u^7\,du
\\&=\int(u^2+2u+3)u^7\,du
\\&=\int u^9+2u^8+3u^7\,du
\\&=\frac{1}{10}u^{10}+\frac{2}{9}u^9+\frac{3}{8}u^8+C
\\&=\frac{1}{10}(x-1)^{10}+\frac{2}{9}(x-1)^9+\frac{3}{8}(x-1)^8+C
\end{align}$

Comment: I suppose that "we can get rid of some of the work" is a real understatement ! $+1$ and Happy New Year !!

Answer (score 1):

$$\int x^2(x-1)^7 dx + 2 \int (x-1)^7 dx $$

Now using integral by parts

$$\int x^2(x-1)^7 dx = x^2\frac{(x-1)^8}{8} - 2\int x\frac{(x-1)^8}{8}dx$$

For $\int x\frac{(x-1)^8}{8}dx$, make $u = x-1 \Rightarrow du =dx$ and $u+1 = x$.

Can you take it from here?